# Antibodies stored in freezer instead of fridge

Tags: antibody

Someone from my lab put the box of antibodies in the freezer instead the fridge.  Can I hope that they will still work?

Comment: Depending on the type of protein and cryoprotectant (eg glycerol), freeze-thaw cycles may or may not damage proteins.

Comment: No way to tell until you try them! If they're in glycerol you have a good chance. We normally store our antibodies in the freezer.

Comment: @anael Have you read manual for that antibodies? Unless they are home-made, there should be one available. If home-made, then ask person who made them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most IgGs should be fine when stored in the freezer.

> Freezing at -20 or -80 in small aliquots is the optimal storage
>   condition. Ali-quoting minimizes damage due to freezing and thawing,
>   as well as contamination introduced by pipetting from a single vial
>   multiple times. Aliquots are to be frozen and thawed once, with any
>   remainder kept at 4 degrees C.
>
> Enzyme-conjugated antibodies, should not be frozen at all and should
>   instead be kept at 4 degrees C. Freezing and thawing will reduce
>   enzymatic activity in addition to affecting the antibody binding
>   capacity.
>
> Antibodies of the IgG3 isotype are unique in their tendency to form
>   aggregates upon thawing and should always be stored at 4 degrees C

Personally, I store antibodies I use at -20 (they are in PBS), and they work fine for the first freeze thaw cycle. I have never tried more than one freeze thaw, so cant comment on that.

http://www.abcam.com/ps/pdf/protocols/antibody_storage.pdf

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify which temperature of freezer you're talking about. Antibody can be stored at -80 for long time, but needs to avoid freeze and thaw process. Some people store aliquot of antibody in -80. Another way is to dilute antibody in Glycerol, make 50% dilution. You need to mix well, and then store at -20.